# Excel | How to Format Number with comma separated

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, ms-office

How to format excel cell with comma separated. For example, we say like 1427322 and it show like 1,427,322
Any suggestion how we can achieve this?

Comment: What happens when you select that format from the Number Format dropdown on the home screen?

Comment: If I use number format, its showing like 14,27,322. But my request here is to show it like 1,427,322

Comment: Control panel -> region & language and change `digit grouping` under **BOTH** currency & numbers to that pattern.

Comment: Great, That worked.!! Thanks a lot Ron

Answer (score 1):

Try this... This worked for me..

Go to Control Panel -> Region (Region & Language) -> In Formats Set format to English(India).

Then apply this custom number format to the specific cell in excel

Apply a custom number format Select the cell or range of cells that you want to format. On the Home tab, under Number, on the Number Format pop-up menu , click Custom. In the Format Cells dialog box, under Category, click Custom. At the bottom of the Type list, select the built-in format that you just created. Click OK.

```
_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* "-"_);_(@_)
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: I have tried the same. But unfortunately its not working. Region was already English India and tried adding the custom format which you have given above. Format is just the same 14,27,322 not giving the expected format 1,427,322

Comment: Thanks a lot Harsha for your suggestions. Ron's suggestion worked.